# Margin doesn't apply when I create an element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating HTML elements using javascript and the CSS margin attribute does not apply a margin.  This is strange since the others attributes are applied correctly.

CSS code:

```
input[type="text"] {
  padding: 5px; 
  margin: 5px;
}
```

The JavaScript:

```
var team1 = document.createElement("input");
team1.type = "text";
team1.placeholder = "Equipa A";
game_det.appendChild(team1);
```

The same issue happens with other element types like the select tag.

Why doesn't the margin apply?

Comment: Can you give an example that demonstrates the problem? Because [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv4ytp61/) seems to work fine.

Comment: Something that catches a lot of people out is the fact that css rules can overwrite other rules. If there are two rules with the same name, any clashing attributes will be taken from the last rule that appears, overwriting values given by earlier rules.That can explain why css in isolation works, yet in large projects fails - the dev has missed the fact that certain attributes are set in more than one place and they grab the desired (but wrong) rule to insert in their forum snippet. I suspect that has happened here to you.

Comment: Is your problem occuring in all browsers or just one/some?

Comment: I tried Chrome and Firefox and the problem occurs in both browsers

Answer (score 1):

Use `inline-block` instead of `inline`.

Comment: Didn't work.
That's odd, because when I create the elements using HTML the margin applies just fine, but the copies I create with javascript don't...

Comment: Part of this answer could be a full reset of the styles. So try adding `position: relative;` (or static) as well as general styling (`width:auto` and such).

Comment: Without seeing an example I can't know for sure, but are you maybe dealing with this: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ ?

Comment: I don't think so, because when I create the element in HTML, using the same tags, classes and everything, the CSS is applied like it should, but when I create the elements in javascript that problem occurs

Answer (score 0):

Try seeing if any margin properties work.

```
margin-top: 5px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-left: 5px;
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you put work correctly, seems to be other issue in your project. 
I changed the CSS a little to see better that is working.

CSS:

```
input[type="text"] {
  padding: 5px; 
  margin: 50px;
}
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/ct6hxxs4/1/

Comment: Not really an answer.

Comment: I've made some tests and problem seems to be other, like you said. I think has something to do with this

.editSport {
  display: inline;
}

.editSport img {
  position: relative; 
  width: 14px; 
  top: 3px; 
  cursor: pointer;
}

The margin problem only occurs in a image I'm appending inside a div

var edit_sport = document.createElement('div');
edit_sport.className = "editSport";
game_det.appendChild(edit_sport);

var edit_img = document.createElement('img');
edit_img.src = "images/edit-icon1.png";
edit_img.onclick = function(){enableSelect(this);};
edit_sport.appendChild(edit_img);

Comment: I wanted to include a prinscreen but looks like I don't have privileges to do that :(

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for trying to help me. I'll try to find a solution, and if I did I'll post where what it is